# What am I doing wrong with my while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, while-loop

I am working on a program that takes in user input (temperatures) and puts it in an array. I am confused on the last method I have to create. I need to go through the array and print them from least to greatest. I need to use a while loop to do this.

The thing is is that I need the index to stay with the temperature values. The index represents the day the temperature was taken. I already have a method that finds the lowest value in the array and prints that along with the index.

Can I just use that method I already have and use it in the new method? If so I have no idea how to call the method while doing a while loop. What I was going to try and do was find the lowest value and print both the value and index and then change the value to my "Uninitialized" variable so I can find the next lowest value and so on.

The last method in my code "LeastToGreatest" is my attempt at doing this but it does not work. I have been working on trying to figure this out for hours on my own. I have no idea what I need to do or how I need to organize this for it to work.

Here is what I have:

```
public class Weather {

static int lowestTemp;
static int lowestDay;

private static final int Uninitialized = -999;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] high = new int[32];


            FindLowestTempInArray(low);
    System.out.println("\n" + "The lowest low is: " + lowestTemp + " degrees." + "\n"
            + "This temperature was recorded on day: " + lowestDay);



            LeastToGreatest(low);
    System.out.println("\n" + lowestDay + "    " + lowestTemp + "\n");


    }


 public static int FindLowestTempInArray(int[] T) {
    // Returns the index of the lowest temperature in array T

    lowestTemp = Uninitialized;
    lowestDay = 0;

    for (int day = 0; day < T.length; day++) {
        if (T[day] != Uninitialized && (T[day] < lowestTemp || lowestTemp == Uninitialized)) {

            lowestTemp = T[day];
            lowestDay = day;
        }
        Arrays.asList(T).indexOf(lowestDay);
    }
    return lowestDay;

}



public static void LeastToGreatest(int[] T) {
    lowestTemp = Uninitialized;
    lowestDay = 0;

    while (lowestDay >= 0 && lowestDay <= 31) {
        for (int day = 0; day < T.length; day++) {

            if (T[day] != Uninitialized && (T[day] < lowestTemp || lowestTemp == Uninitialized)) {

                lowestTemp = T[day];
                lowestDay = day;

            }
        }

    }

    }
```

}

Comment: If I was doing this i would store the temperatures and the day numbers as two columns in an array, so the array would be 2x31 of int.  Then I'd sort it by the temperature field.  The final value would be the highest and simply outputting the array would be in order of temperature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse your other method in here.

```
public static void leastToGreates(int[] temps) {
    // copying the old array temps into newTempArr
    int[] newTempArr = new int[temps.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++)
        newTempArr[i] = temps[i];

    int days = 0;
    while (days < temps.length) {
        int lowest = FindLowestTempInArray(newTempArr);
        if (newTempArr[lowest] > Uninitialized)
            System.out.println("temp: " + newTempArr[lowest] + ", on day: " + lowest);
        // setting the temperature of the current lowest day to "Uninitialized"
        // (so it's not the lowest temperature anymore)
        newTempArr[lowest] = Uninitialized;
        days++;
    }
}
```

What I do here is:

- Copy the temperatures array (in order to be able to change values in it) without affecting the original array
- print the lowest temperature in the array
- set the temperature of that index to "Uninitialized"
- repeat

Comment: Why does it print out "temp: 2147483647, on day: 4" 30 times?

Comment: i can only guess but i think that's because you used the `lowestTemperature` in your other method... This will probably only work if all of the days are set with a valid temperature (not with -999)

Comment: The new code works perfect! Thanks for showing me how to do this!